# Multiple ListBox on same Window doesn't select when focus moving ListBox

Tags: c#

I have two `ListBox` in my window: `LstStoreItems` and `LstPlayerItems`. It looks like this:

[image]

The idea here is that when you select an item from the Store, the `Sell` button is disabled, and it `UnselectAll` on the Player Inventory, and vise Versa. Here's the code:

```
    private void LstPlayerItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LstStoreItems.UnselectAll();
        BtnBuy.IsEnabled = false;
        BtnSell.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void LstStoreItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LstPlayerItems.UnselectAll();
        BtnBuy.IsEnabled = true;
        BtnSell.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Now, though, if I select an item in the Player Inventory, and then go to select an item in the Store Inventory, it executes the code, but it doesn't actually select the item I'd clicked. How can I get it to select the item when I'm changing the focused ListBox?

Comment: You can use the listboxes click events instead of their selection_changed events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is going on is the other ListBox's `SelectionChanged` event is being triggered when you do your UnSelectAll which is causing your new selected item to be unselected. Try checking to make sure that you have a selected item in ListBox before unselecting the items in the other ListBox.
Something like this:

```
private void LstPlayerItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex != -1)
        LstStoreItems.UnselectAll();
    BtnBuy.IsEnabled = false;
    BtnSell.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void LstStoreItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex != -1)
        LstPlayerItems.UnselectAll();
    BtnBuy.IsEnabled = true;
    BtnSell.IsEnabled = false;
}
```